# How can I add a panGestureRocgnizer To a TableView, and still have the tableview scroll while recognizing pans right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm using an ECSlidingViewController (github hamburger-menu/slide-out menu project).

I have a TableViewController, and I need to add the following to my TableViewController.

```
        ECSlidingViewController *ecsVC = (ECSlidingViewController *)viewController;
        ecsVC.panGesture.delegate = self;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:ecsVC.panGesture];
```

I cannot do `self.navigationcontroller.view addGestu...`, because if I push a view, then I still get the pangesture functionality which I don't want. I just want it on this one view.

So I must do `self.VIEW addGest...`. However, as soon as I do this the tableView stops scrolling.

If I pan my finger right, the hamburger menu slides out, but like I said, my tableview won't scroll.

So, I've tried to use `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {` but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly.

If I return YES, my hamburger menu slides out, but my tableview doesn't work/scroll. If I return NO, the hamburger menu doesn't work/slide out but the tableView works.

So I need to distinguish between the two and return YES/NO accordingly.

However, how can I distinguish the different?

I can't use target/action on the panGesture, because then `-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch` is never called (meaning I can't make the tableview scroll). And if I cast the gestureRecognizer to UIPanGestureRecognizer in `-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch`, and use `-velocityInView`, because I only get the initial tap. So I only get X & Y of 0.0 each.

How can I recognize whether the user is swiping left or not in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if (ABS(translation.x) > ABS(translation.y)) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```